# LogCat Meaning of an error in my app

Tags: android

I have something from my logcat that i need helped explained. I tried google, but not much help. This is the message:

E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0

I'm trying to see if I can get some help on what the meanin of this may be so I can correct it. Thanks.

```
package app.com.example.android.shoutoutapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.add_photo))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

        public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wrote the code mina fawzy

Comment: That's it. Your logcat has only one line? Show us more please.

Comment: I'm trying, but that is the only error in the logcat Stephan Branczyk